# How to make bonds thicker in ChemDraw?

Tags: molecular-structure, software, notation

I often see molecules depicted using ChemDraw with all or selected bonds visibly thicker than those used with the style defined with [ACS-1996](https://pubs.acs.org/page/4authors/submission/graphics_prep.html) template.
For example, see the PDF handouts for [Baran's laboratory group seminars](https://baranlab.org/research/seminars/) created with ChemDraw, for instance, [Biotech: A High Stakes Table for Science (Garrido-Castro, 2022)](https://baranlab.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/LongLit_220827_2.pdf) (PDF):

> [image: Illustration from Baran's GM]

Another example would be an illustration produced in Meng et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/jacs.0c04074)]:

> [image: Intermediate in molecular recognition-enabled remote C–H oxidation (Crabtree)]

Where can I find the relevant parameters for the bond thickness control in ChemDraw?

#### Reference

1. Meng, G.; Lam, N. Y. S.; Lucas, E. L.; Saint-Denis, T. G.; Verma, P.; Chekshin, N.; Yu, J.-Q. Achieving Site-Selectivity for C–H Activation Processes Based on Distance and Geometry: A Carpenter’s Approach. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **2020**, 142 (24), 10571–10591. DOI: [10.1021/jacs.0c04074](https://doi.org/10.1021/jacs.0c04074).

Comment: Did you try "File -> Document Settings … -> Drawing" to set your own value, or "File -> Apply  Document Settings from" to use a predefined one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChemDraw stores *styles* as `*.cds` files (while *templates*, about structures, glass ware, etc as `*.ctp`).  They are in a binary format Windows stores in a folder of `.../ChemOffice20XX/ChemDraw/ChemDrawItems` with a varying string of `ChemOffice20XX` - depending on the version of ChemDraw installed.

Anyone can create a style file from scratch.  Or can adjusting one already provided (ACS, RCS, ...) by ChemDraw and save it as a new style.  Phil Baran's choice to use a non-serif font Arial (?) but *bold* arguably is not *that* unique.  It equally is seen for example in the retrosynthesis books by Warren and Wyatt, or in *Classics in Total Synthesis* by Nicolaou and Snyder.  Hence, if you want a formula similar like

[image]

and don't get in touch with any of the authors / the author's groups mentioned, you can play with the parameters similar to the ones the .gif outlines below.

[image]

I think there is a recommendation to cite references on chemistry.se in the pattern of ACS journals, but do not recall if there equally is dedicated "use this (or any other *specific*) style to format structure formulae" rule here.  Hence it is not surprising, authors on chemistry.se use a style a sketcher offers by default, which is not too personalized.

Book references:

Warren, S.; Wyatt, P. Organic Synthesis: The Disconnection Approach. Wiley, 2008, ISBN 978-0-470-71236-8 ([link](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Organic+Synthesis%3A+The+Disconnection+Approach%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780470712368) to the publisher's landing page).

Nicolaou, K. C.; Snyder S. A. Classics in Total Synthesis II: More Targets, Strategies, Methods. Wiley, 2003, ISBN 978-3-527-30684-8 ([link](https://www.wiley.com/en-cn/Classics+in+Total+Synthesis+II%3A+More+Targets%2C+Strategies%2C+Methods-p-9783527306848) to the publisher's landing page).